# JS To call external to run a php script

Tags: php, javascript

I have a PHP Script to update a database, I have the PHP Side nailed down, but the JS I'm having a little bit of trouble with. Below is my code:

```
$JSON = json_decode($Arg);
$Username = $JSON['Username'];
$Page = $JSON['Location'];

$Query = $MySQLi->prepare("INSERT INTO Requests (username, page) VALUES (?, ?)");
$Query-> bind_param("ss", $DUsername, $Page);
$Query->execute();

$Query_2 = $MySQLi->query("UPDATE RequestStats SET Count = Count+1, LastRequest='NOW()'");
```

And on the user side,

```
if (isset($_POST['Request']))
{
 $EmptyArray = array();
 $EmptyArray[] = $Username;
 $EmptyArray[] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 json_encode($EmptyArray);
}
```

What I need done, is calling a Javascript/AJAX chunk to forward over the request to my external page, and dynamically update the database without a refresh.. After the request is made, echo out a box saying "your request has been made, and you are number: `number` inline"

I have no idea on how to do this, could anyone provide some assistance?

Comment: Have you done a tutorial on Ajax? Seems like a logical place to start.

Comment: I have researched into Ajax, I have a possible lead using the `ICallbackEventHandler`

Comment: You reading .NET stuff? I have no idea how that would help you out. Read about the [XMLHttpRequest Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be completed by using JQuery... View the manual for what i've used: 
http://api.jquery.com/click/

Userside:

```
<body>
<div id="test">
<input type="button" value="Make A Request">
</div>


<script>
$("#test").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'page.php',
        success: function(){
             alert('Created');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: This works on making the External Page run, but how would I go about sending my data through it?

Comment: Use the manual. Search the manual. Feel the manual. 
http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON